# Dplyr pipe operation obtaining minimum

Tags: r, dplyr

When trying to combine R pipe operations with obtaining a minimum, I came across this issue. I would expect this to work but it doesn't. Can anyone explain to me why this is the case, and how to fix it?

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
                 Name = c("Name1", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3"),
                 Value = c(10, 14, 13, 1))

df <- df %>%
        filter(grepl("name1", Name, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
        min(Value) 

Error in function_list[[k]](value) : object 'Value' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `pull` the column 'Value' as a `vector` and get the `min`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
       filter(grepl("name1", Name, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>% 
       pull(Value) %>% 
       min
```

Or use `summarise`

```
 df %>%
       filter(grepl("name1", Name, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
       summarise(Value = min(Value))
```

---

The reason is that the output from the `%>%` is the full dataset, we need to extract the column with `$` or `[[`

```
df %>%
    filter(grepl("name1", Name, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
     {min(.$Value)}
#[1] 10
```